# Convert rtf to docx file in Java without third party library

Tags: java, arrays, io, docx, rtf

Is there any way to convert a file in rtf format to docx format without third party libraries such as aspose etc. I tried to use InputStream and OutputStream but it leads to a corrupted docx file.

```
private static void convertToDoc() throws IOException {
        String inputPath = "C:\\inputFile.rtf";
        String OutputPath = "C:\\outputFile.docx";
        File initialFile = new File(inputPath);
        InputStream source = new FileInputStream(initialFile);
        OutputStream target = new FileOutputStream(OutputPath);
        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
        int length;
        while ((length = source.read(buf)) > 0) {
            target.write(buf, 0, length);
        }
        source.close();
        target.close();
    }
```

Comment: MS Word, WordPad or Libre Office can open RTF files. What exactly you want to do with the file?

Comment: I have an rtf file and I want to edit it with docx4j library. I cannot load it directly so I want to convert it first in a docx format.

Comment: It seems you missed an important point here. You changed the filename extension but not the content itself. The Rich Text Format and the Microsoft Word Document format are totally different file formats. This means the file contents are different. If you have enough time you can try to find the specifications for both file formats and implement a transformation on your own. Or you can use some libraries. Or you can use Word controlled by your program or via VBA.

Comment: Java swing can load an RTF document as styled document. I am not sure whether that is helpful.